# React Native mobx binding to FlatList not working

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, react-native-flatlist

I have a RN (0.44.2) `mobx` (3.1.10) app which uses a `FlatList`. I'm basically following https://blog.callstack.io/write-react-native-apps-in-2017-style-with-mobx-e2dffc209fcb

When using my own store, opposed to the examples, I'm having to use `toJS()` in order to get the FlastList to render

```
    // renders list
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.giphyStore.images.toJS()}
      keyExtractor={(_, i) => i}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>found the data</Text>}
    />

    // does not render list
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.giphyStore.images}
      keyExtractor={(_, i) => i}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>did not find the data</Text>}
    />
```

I'm really struggling to figure out why `toJS()` might be needed in some cases and not others.

My store is setting the images observable like this

```
async getImageList(query: string) {
  try {
    const requestURL = `${constants.GIPHY_ENDPOINT}${query}`
    const response = await axios.get(requestURL);
    const imgs = response.data.data.map((item) => {
      return { id: item.id, url: item.images.downsized.url }
    })
    this.images.replace(imgs)
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

As a follow up question, I'm not sure why I need to do the following `this.images.replace(imgs)` where as in the tutorial he simply did does `this.tracks = response.data.tracks.items` which triggers the observable just fine.

If anyone has suggestions, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: May be related to [this](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/gh-pages/docs/best/react.md#incorrect-access-out-of-bounds-indices-in-tracked-function)

Comment: In react-native you can use in FlatList, data={toJS(listStore.things)} or use data={[...listStore.things]}. 

Two ways works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because **mobx's** arrays are objects and the data in `FlatList` or in **react native** expects an array. You can read more about it in [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/gh-pages/docs/best/react.md#incorrect-access-out-of-bounds-indices-in-tracked-function) and [there](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/476).

[Also...](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html#observable-arrays), `slice` returns a shallow copy; a new array with the same contents, while `toJS` also converts the values inside the array (but only if they are observables).

Answer (score 3):

This question is kinda old, but it's also worth mentioning that MobX only tracks the render function by default, while `FlatList` accepts rendering callbacks and calls them. (eg `renderItem={this.renderItem}`)

In order for items to update without the whole list refreshing, wrap the render callback's result with `<Observer>`.

See [Understanding reactivity [Mobx docs]](https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html)