# ListItem not rerendering in FlatList when observable array changes

Tags: react-native, mobx, listitem, react-native-flatlist

I have component called CheckListItem that contains:

```
<ListItem
    leftAvatar={this.props.leftAvatar}
    title={this.props.title}
    leftIcon={this.state.icon}
       onPress={(event) => {
          this.props.onSelect();
       }}
    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}
    switch={{ value: this.props.isSelected, disabled: true }} // <-- this switch
/>
```

I export it as an observer:

```
export default (observer(CheckListItem));
```

And use it from my so called CountryPage:

```
render() {
    console.log(toJS(this.props.store.countries)); // <-- prints the expected updated list
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>{this.state.ouputText}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.store.countries}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <CheckListItem
                    title={item.name}
                    leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.flag } }}
                    onSelect={() => { SearchParameters.getInstance().setCountrySelected(item.key); }}
                    isSelected={item.isSelected} //<-- won't update
                    />
                }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

I inject my store which is the singleton instance of SearchParameters

```
export default inject('store')(observer(CountryPage));
```

Whenever I get my SearchParameters instance and change any of the properties inside the list (`isSelected`) that resides there. CountryPage rerenders and log the expected updated list. My problem is that this don't update CheckListItem - and rerenders it. How can I make my CheckListItem component receive the updated props whenever the list elements change and rerender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer is the second answer here: [React Native mobx binding to FlatList not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248562/react-native-mobx-binding-to-flatlist-not-working). Adding Observer around CheckListItem made it so that the 'isSelected' was passed down thus updating the switch.

```
render() {
    console.log(toJS(this.props.store.countries));
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>{this.state.ouputText}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.store.countries}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <Observer>
                        {() => 
                        <CheckListItem
                        title={item.name}
                        leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.flag } }}
                        onSelect={() => { SearchParameters.getInstance().setCountrySelected(item.key); }}
                        isSelected={item.isSelected}
                        />
                        }
                    </Observer>
                    }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```